# Exclude specific instance from the field in serialization Django REST API

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework

I want to get the list of user's chats (fields are: chat id, chat participants), but I don't want the user itself to be listed among chat participants (I mean user has to be among chat participants for sure, but there is no need for user to see his own name listed among other names when he requests the list of his chats, as it is pointless).

Here is the Chat model:

```
class Chat(models.Model):
id = models.CharField(_('id'), primary_key=True, default=hex_uuid, editable=False, max_length=32)
chat_participants = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)

class Meta:
    db_table = 'chat'
    verbose_name_plural = 'chats'
```

Here is Chat serializer:

```
class ChatSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    chat_participants = ChatParticipantsSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Chat
        fields = '__all__'
```

PS ChatParticipantsSerializer (which's model is User) is for getting the name and surname of the participants, and not only their id's.

Here is the view:

```
class ChatsListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
serializer_class = ChatSerializer

def get_queryset(self):
    return Chat.objects.filter(chat_participants=self.request.user.id)
```

PS in get_queryset function I check if the user in the chat group (if he is among the chat participants of the group)

Now I get in JSON this:

```
[
{
    "id": "a38609b1c86f4d71b0b300381db747b4",
    "chat_participants": [
        {
            "id": "044ad4f8876d4b8bb057a63769a33027",
            "first_name": "Jean",
            "last_name": "Mel"
        },
        {
            "id": "c01473b5d72a4b0ea40a4047ed297d77",
            "first_name": "Sasha",
            "last_name": "King"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": "4fdf4a34eaf6464baf55b08676b7d6a6",
    "chat_participants": [
        {
            "id": "c01473b5d72a4b0ea40a4047ed297d77",
            "first_name": "Sasha",
            "last_name": "King"
        },
        {
            "id": "ffcf4d06958b4926bee833166279f0c6",
            "first_name": "Anne",
            "last_name": "Brown"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Here is my list of chats in JSON format. So I got the IDs of chats, and ALL the participants in the chats (here are just two participants in each). If I am Sasha King, how can I remove this name from chat participants in JSON, as there is no point to show the name of the user to himself (Dunno, maybe to write a function excluding self.request.user in serializer itself...)

I want to get this:

```
 [
    {
        "id": "a38609b1c86f4d71b0b300381db747b4",
        "chat_participants": [
            {
                "id": "044ad4f8876d4b8bb057a63769a33027",
                "first_name": "Jean",
                "last_name": "Mel"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "4fdf4a34eaf6464baf55b08676b7d6a6",
        "chat_participants": [
            {
                "id": "ffcf4d06958b4926bee833166279f0c6",
                "first_name": "Anne",
                "last_name": "Brown"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: can you also list `ChatParticipantsSerializer`.

Comment: do you mean to show ChatParticipantsSerializer? If yes, here it is:                                   class ChatParticipantsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name']

Answer (score 0):

I havnt tested the code, but the idea should work.
Basically you filter the participants than you serialize them "manually"

```
class ChatSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    chat_participants = SerializerMethod()

    class Meta:
        model = Chat
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_chat_participants(self, obj):
        return ChatParticipantsSerializer(obj.chat_participants.exclude(self.context["request"].user) many=True, read_only=True).data
```